# .net 4.0 chart control custom grid line

Tags: asp.net, charts, .net-4.0

Is it possible to customise how the grid lines appear. I have two charts one shows daily data - with Time as x axis. I would like grid-line to show on the hour or for example every 2 hours. In the second chart the x axis is across a date range so I would like grid-line to be for every day or for example every 5 days.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the ChartArea's AxisX's IntervalType and Interval properties:

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX = new Axis() {
    IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours,
    Interval = 2
};

chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX = new Axis() {
    IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days,
    Interval = 5
};
```